# Check if a latitude and longitude is within a circle in swift using apple maps?

Tags: swift, swift4, apple-maps

[image]

i want know, if i give a set of latitude and longitude within a circle and radius

Comment: "I want know", it is expected when you ask a question that you have done some research first and also have some code to show what you have tried and to help explain your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use: `distance(from:`

```
let distance = usersLocation.distance(from: circleCenter)

if distance > maxRadius { print("outside of range") }
```